# TinyMCE buttons by content type

Tags: nodes, wysiwyg, files

I installed tinyMCE with IMCE in my Drupal 7 site. I'm finding a way to show different buttons in tinyMCE editor by each content type. For example, the image button is displayed for the Article content type, but it will not be displayed for my custom content type.
Is there a way to set this up with the existing module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 text-formats.  Allow "Image" in tinyMCE profile of one text-format and not allow it for the other.

To set fixed text-format to each text-area field, you can use Better Formats module.  Download from http://drupal.org/project/better_formats and install it.

In "Managed Field" page of your text-area field, check "Filtered text (user selects text format)" and "Limit text format".  You will see all your defined text-formats with leading check-boxes.

Click the check-box of a text-format and save.  In your "Add Content" page, you will see your text-area is assigned with respective tinyMCE editor.

Comment: You really helped me. Thanks! When I installed Better Formats, I could chose "Allowed formats" in the field configuration page of the respective content type. But one thing is that the module is still beta release.